# KnockoutJS/Bootstrap - Clearing modal form when closing modal using javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, twitter-bootstrap, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a Bootstrap Modal that contains a form for updating or creating an entity (Company in my example). Right now my issue is that if I view an entity using the modal, it doesn't clear out the fields when I close the modal by any means. Causing the form to still be populated if I then click a "Create" button, which should bring me up a blank modal.

How can I execute one of my ViewModels methods from just regular javascript? Here is *some* of my code:

```
function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;

       function CompanyViewModel(company) {
            var self = this;
            self.Id = company.CompanyId;
            self.Name = company.Name;
        }

        function BlankCompanyViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.Id = 0;
            self.Name = "";
        }

        self.company = ko.observable();
        self.companies = ko.observableArray();


        self.clearCurrentCompany = function() {
            self.company(new BlankCompanyViewModel());
        };

       // Initialize the view-model
        $.getJSON("/api/company", function(companies) {
            $.each(companies, function(index, company) {
                self.companies.push(new CompanyViewModel(company));
            });
            self.clearCurrentCompany();
        });
    }
```

Ideally I'd like to run ViewModel.clearCurrentCompany on the "Hidden" event of the modal like so:

```
 $('#myModal').on('hidden', function() {
       //Do something here, not sure what
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    // your previous code
    $('#myModal').on('hide', function() {
       self.clearCurrentCompany();
    });
}
```

Just like that. Note that you want hide, not hidden, because hidden fires only after the modal completely disappears. If a user opens a create before the previous view closes, it will still be populated.

Comment: self.clearCurrentCompany(); won't work because it is outside of the context of the ViewModel.

Comment: Another interesting option would be to handle the visibility of the modal through knockout subscriptions. You could bind modal display to the company event:

self.company.subscribe(function(company) {
    if (company) { $('#myModal').modal('show'); }
    else { $('#myModal').modal('hide'); }
});

The solution is more complicated than this, and this is by no means a better solution, just a different paradigm and a different way of looking at the structure of the program.

Comment: It is not. The variable self has been defined for the scope of ViewModel(), so it is still defined within the onHide function, so long as the onHide function is defined within the viewModel and self is not redefined in a child scope.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, it works. I should've been able to figure this out. Sometimes talking it trough helps. :)

Answer (score 4):

I like to use a custom binding around a modal to make it open/close/display based on populating/clearing an observable.

Something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.modal = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, vm, context) {
        var modal = valueAccessor();
        //init the modal and make sure that we clear the observable no matter how the modal is closed
        $(element).modal({ show: false, backdrop: 'static' }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modal)) {
                modal(null);
            }
        });

        //apply the template binding to this element
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { with: modal }, context);

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var data = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        //show or hide the modal depending on whether the associated data is populated
        $(element).modal(data ? "show" : "hide");
    }
};
```

You then use this against an observable. It acts like a `with` binding against that observable and shows/hides the modal based on whether the observable is populated.

Here is a sample that shows this in use and sets up a subscription where you could run custom code when the modal is closed.  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/uf3DF/