# Knockout Binding Handlers undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6G7r/) which shows a table and some users with roles.

I want to have a modal form pop up when some clicks add roles etc.

There seems to be an error on the update property of this `ko.bindingHandlers.modal` function:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.modal = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).modal({ show: false }).on("hidden", function () {
            var data = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(data))
                data(null);
        });

        return ko.bindingHandlers["with"].init.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var data = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        $(element).modal( data ? "show" : "hide" );

        return ko.bindingHandlers["with"].update.apply(this, arguments); // Error on this line
    }
};
```

I don't why this is happening, I have copied the code from Ryan Niemeyer [dev video](http://vimeo.com/73627803)

Its 34mins in.

It's a Bootstrap modal dialogue, using Knockout JS as the binding library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with` binding does no longer have the update function

From the init function use

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { with: valueAccessor() });
```

Update

```
ko.bindingHandlers.modal = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).modal({ show: false }).on("hidden", function () {
            var data = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(data))
                data(null);
        });



        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { with: valueAccessor() }, bindingContext);

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var data = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        $(element).modal( data ? "show" : "hide" );;
    }
};
```

Comment: @No1_Melman It was 9 months ago, probably not the same knockout version than the one you use

Comment: Okay so where about does that line go, in before the return?

Comment: yes- the `with` binding's `update` function was removed in a recent version (change was in KO 3.1).  In your case, you could just remove the call to the `with` binding's `update` call completely from the `update` handler.  Another option would be to use the call that @Anders listed in the `init` function, although you would want to pass the context as the third argument (context is 5th argument that comes into init/update functions) and you would want to `return { controlsDescendantBindings: true;` from the `init`.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer could you edit the jsfiddle for me, as I find it quite hard to understand the written text?

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/aAP9P/.  The hidden event name needed a change too with this version of bootstrap.  Anders version will work fine too.

Comment: yeah i put that in :)

Comment: Glad it is working. Code turned out like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573196/knockoutjs-bootstrap-clearing-modal-form-when-closing-modal-using-javascript/16573700#16573700

Comment: Another tip is also to render the modal related content using a template binding with a string source engine so that the binding takes care of rendering the modal stuff for you. I have an example of that here (jQuery tabs binding) https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings/blob/master/src/knockout.bindings.js#L237